# Difference between inner and outer join

Tags: mysql, join, server

I don't get the difference between this `INNER JOIN` and this `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The `INNER JOIN` is the given solution for me. I came up with the idea with the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Both work, but what is the best solution?

Why I do a INNER Join here?

```
SELECT * 
FROM world.city  
INNER JOIN country ON (world.country.code=world=world.city.countryCode)  
WHERE continent = "North America"
```

My own Solution is this:

```
SELECT City.Name, City.Population, City.CountryCode  
FROM City  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Country ON City.CountryCode = Country.Code  
WHERE Country.Continent = "North America"
```

Why is this a bad solution?

Why SQL knows that continent belongs to the Table `country` and not to the Table "city"?(like `Country.Continent`)

Comment: Both Selects return the same result, because the Outer Join is logically equivalent to the Inner Join: *Give me all cities where the continent is known to be "North America"*. This is a bad solution if the optimizer is not smart enough to recognize that, actually joins all rows first and then filters the result (I don't know if MySQL is still that stupid). When you move `AND continent = "North America"` to `ON` it will return all cities, but `NULL` for all other continents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner join : it will give all the cities which are having country code .means it will skip countries and cities which does not have corresponding row

Left outer join : this will give you joins with left table preference.if corresponding key in right table is not present even though it will show city it will give all cities even if country is null

Right outer join :this will prefer right table if key is not present in left table. It will also include countries whose cities are not present in city table

Answer (score 1):

Because your `WHERE` clause includes a condition on the joined table `Country`, you are effectively forcing an `INNER JOIN` in your second query. If you where to put that condition in your `ON` clause, you would see a different result. In your 2nd example, this would yield all the rows in the `Country` table instead of just the ones you want.

Comment: Okay, could you please give me an example, where the ON condition gives me a different result?

Comment: Added what would happen it your second query.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a image of the difference of JOINS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@wogsland's explains why your query using outer join was a bad solution.  This is your other question:  "Why SQL knows that continent belongs to the Table country and not to the Table "city"?(like Country.Continent)"

SQL knows the columns in the city table.  Had there been one called continent, your query would have thrown an error.  The message varies from RDBMS to RDBMS, but it's words to the effect of an ambiguous column name.  I don't work with mySQL so I don't know their specific wording.